# Use Order By with Three UNION in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three union and i need to order them Or use another Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT episode.episode_id,episode.ep_title , series.series_id, 
series.title, series.pic FROM episode RIGHT JOIN series ON 
episode.series_oid=series.series_id UNION SELECT * FROM movies"
```

[My episode table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/741Wp.png)

[movie table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgPyU.png)

[series table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9CNc.png)

Comment: The UNION's first and second SELECT must return same number of columns. (And their data types must be compatible.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: how i can do it

Comment: When editing, write sample data in proper columns. Mark it. Click `{}`.

Comment: can we fix it in facebook chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UNION you must use the same number of columns and matching datatype

use null for absent columns

And i suggest you the inversion of table name the the use of left join

```
SELECT episode.episode_id
  , episode.ep_title
  , episode.post_date 
  , series.series_id
  , series.title
  , series.pic 
FROM series
LEFT  JOIN episode ON episode.series_oid=series.series_id 
UNION ALL 
SELECT mov_id
, mov_title
, post_date
, null
, null
, null 
FROM movies 
ORDER BY post_date
```

Comment: @jarlh  .. thanks for (right) editing

Comment: i get an error Unknown column 'episode.episode_id' in 'field list'

Comment: could be is episode_oid ?? .. answer  updated  ..but is taken form your code  ..  i just changed  the join and the null columns

Comment: i edited my code can you check it again this code is working

Comment: i have edited  the code for match the column name in your picture

Comment: still same error

Comment: show us also the series  table schema  and post you actul query code  too

Comment: i edited the post and i add my series table

Comment: answer  updated ..  series_id and not series_oid

Comment: it worked but not ordred you define post_date as null can you fix it

Comment: ITS WORK THANK YOU SER

Comment: BUT CAN YOU DO ONE OTHER THINK FOR ME

Comment: @AGOUCHAMSOU   you should post a new proper question with 
 your code a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. eventually  comment me the link to the new question

Comment: HEY PLEASE I NEED YOUR HELP IN MY PROJECT CAN YOU ADD ME IN FACEBOOK

Comment: .@AGOUCHAMSOU  .. is not the my  rules..    i'm sorry  ..

Comment: ok thank you for your answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431998/if-statment-to-check-data-from-which-table mY NEW QUESTION

Comment: Hey in the other question i fix it but cant data from the movies table it say unifined index for all rows of movies